# TYPO3: disable trustedProperties

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Is there a way to disable "trustedProperties" in f:form?

For some reason I get the following output in the hidden field:

```
s:11:&qquot;description&quot;
```

This results is a parse error because of the duplicated "q".

Comment: You need to find out why the `&quot;` gets two `q` there. This is the source of the problem.

Comment: I do know. I further track down the problem I would like to temporarely disable trustedProperties

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the `trustedProperties`, but you can tell the action to ignore it with the annotation `@ignorevalidation`.

But as cweiske says, you should look for the double "q" which is the main problem here. You can't add a "q" at this position by misconfiguring the fields. The problem must be created by another thing like e.g. a JS going wild.